# Gmail keyboard shortcut to jump to specific label?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut that will allow me to jump to a specific label folder in Gmail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot choose a shortcut for a custom label.

Anyway, you can access gmail default label with shortcuts :

```
^b chats
^f sent mail
^i inbox
^k trash
^r draft
^s spam
^t starred messages
^u unread mail
```

Or, you can use `l` to access the label menu (described [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6594)) and then choose your label.

And btw, here is a [cheatsheet](http://r.evhead.com/hodgepodge/gmail-shortcuts.html) for Gmail shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

The shortcut `gl` allows you to go to a label within Gmail.

Press `gl` and "label:" will appear in Gmail's search bar, along with a drop-down list of some labels. Type the first few letters of the label and select it, and you'll be taken to that label.